# Visual Studio 2015 Always opens as Administrator

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I open Visual Studio 2015 it opens as Admin.
At the top left of the Visual Studio screen it shows:
Start Page - Microsoft Visual Studio (Administrator)

I looked in the properties of the shortcut under Advanced Properties and "Run as administrator is NOT checked.

Please tell me how to make Visual Studio 2015 to **NOT** open as administrator.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling, ensuring the shortcuts have gone and then reinstalling?

Comment: Have you disabled UAC on this machine? What happens if you simply open a command prompt? Is it also saying Administrator?